# Can you delete users that aren't verified for a certain period of time in Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I make a Swift app with Firebase Auth to manage my users. If I want to delete users, that didn't verify over the link in the verification email for a certain period of time, is there a Firebase option to delete them automatically?

Comment: You can run your own server-side code in Firebase so just program a script that does that, nothing to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can write script to delete non verified user and run it when you want, using Firebase admin sdk, https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Something like that (Here is a java code)

```
ListUsersPage page = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().listUsers(null);
while (page != null) {
  for (ExportedUserRecord user : page.getValues()) {
    if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(user.getUid());
    }
    System.out.println("User: " + user.getUid());
  }
  page = page.getNextPage();
}
```

This SDK written in Node.js,    Java,   Python, Go, C#

Comment: Do I have to create a new Java project for that or does it run on the server?

Comment: it depends on your requirements, i think java app will be cheap and simple!

Comment: But I need an external jar file that is just connected to the Firebase Server with the Admin SDK?

Comment: For `deleteUser()` docs from provided link, on that page click: [User Management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)